# Lighttpd custom configuration mysql vhost

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, lighttpd

Here is what i want to do

I have to stand-alone websites that i want to run: siteA.maindomain,com and siteB.maindomain.com

For siteB i want to be able to vhost subdomainX.siteB.maindomain.com using the mod_mysql_vhos.

Here is how my lighttpd.conf file looks:

```
server.modules              = (
            "mod_access",
            "mod_alias",
            "mod_accesslog",
            "mod_compress",
            "mod_mysql_vhost",
            "mod_ssi",
            "mod_rewrite"
)



include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/include-conf-enabled.pl"

ssi.extension = ( ".html" )
server.document-root       = "/var/www/maindomain/htdocs"
server.errorlog            = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
accesslog.filename         = "/var/log/lighttpd/access.log"
index-file.names           = ( "index.php", "index.html",
                               "index.htm", "default.htm",
                               "index.lighttpd.html" )



fastcgi.debug = 1

static-file.exclude-extensions = (".pl", ".fcgi" )

server.port               = 80
server.bind               = "11.22.33.44"
server.pid-file           = "/var/run/lighttpd.pid"

dir-listing.encoding        = "utf-8"
server.dir-listing          = "disable"

server.username            = "www-data"
server.groupname           = "www-data"

compress.cache-dir          = "/var/cache/lighttpd/compress/"
compress.filetype           = ("text/plain", "text/html", "application/x-javascript", "text/css")

#include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.assign.pl"


mysql-vhost.db             = "vhost"
mysql-vhost.user           = "lighttpd"
mysql-vhost.pass           = "correct_password"
mysql-vhost.sql            = "SELECT docroot FROM domains WHERE domain='?';"
mysql-vhost.hostname       = "localhost"
mysql-vhost.port           = 3306

$HTTP["host"] == "siteA.maindomain.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/siteA/htdocs"
    accesslog.filename = "/var/www/siteA/htdocs/logs/access.log"
    server.errorlog  = "/var/www/siteA/htdocs/logs/error.log"

}

$HTTP["host"] == "siteB.maindomain.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/www/siteB/htdocs"
    accesslog.filename = "/var/www/siteB/htdocs/logs/access.log"
    server.errorlog = "/var/www/siteB/htdocs/logs/error.log"    
}
```

Is this ok ?

siteA.maindomain.com works fine.

I can't access the siteB.maindomain.com URL. I get 404. What am i doing wrong.

I am sure i didn't configure this correctly to vhost subdomainX.siteB.maindomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set up siteB/htdocs correctly.
Since siteA works, you might try (temporarily) changing siteB.maindomain.com
`server.document-root = "/var/www/siteB/htdocs"`
to
`server.document-root = "/var/www/siteA/htdocs"`
and then see if that works.

Also, you might want to log into the mysql database to check if siteB.maindomain.com is configured in the vhost database.